# Sorting with clicking on a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have something like this:

```
%section
  %h1= t('.MyTableData')
  .row-fluid
    .span8
      %table.table
        %thead
          %tr
            %th= sortable('teachers', 'teacher_name', 'true')
            %th= sortable('teachers', 'teacher_score')
            %th= sortable('teachers', 'specialty')
        %tbody
          - @teachers.each do |teacher|
            %tr
              %td= as_full_name(teacher[:first_name], teacher[:last_name])
              %td= number_to_percentage(provider[:teacher_score], precision: 0)
              %td= provider[:specialty_name]                  
    .span2
      =render partial: 'search'
```

So it creates a table with some columns, if I click on the column headers like teacher_name, etc it will sort the table based on that using that sortable method.

Now I want to add a simple twitter bootstrap **button** saying **"Reset Sorting"**, and when I click that it should reset these sorting we have done by clicking on column headers and go and sort it only by `teacher_name.`

I am very new to all this and can't put these pieces of puzzle together, so I need a button, and the sort method I need there is some samples of it in that sortable methods, But can't figure out how to put all these together and solve this.

```
  def sortable(table, column, default_column = false)
    table_params = params[table] || {}

    same_sort_column = same_sort_column(table_params, column, default_column)
    current_sort_direction = sort_direction(table_params)

    new_direction = same_sort_column && current_sort_direction == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc'

    link_to(t(".#{column}"), params.merge(table => { sort_column: column, sort_direction: new_direction }))
  end
```

Comment: You should provide "sortable" method implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= link_to 'Reset sorting', params.merge(:teachers => {:sort_column => 'teacher_name', :sort_direction => 'asc'}), :class => 'btn'
```

Comment: Thanks, does it also "reset" all other previous sorting that have been done on the table? For example we start clicking on a bundle on column on the table, it starts getting sorted by them...so we use your code, so it only now sorts by teacher_name?

Comment: It resets sorting column to "teacher_name" after any sequence of clicks on sorting links. This is what you mean? But I'm not sure about direction. You can test it or provide "same_sort_column" and "sort_direction" methods implemenation